# How can I make the docstring in PyCharm as helpful as the one in the Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

**Jupyter Notebook**
Documentation upon typing the command and "()" and pressing Shift+Tab in the Jupyter Notebook (a nice docstring with all parameters explained and examples shows up):
[image]

**PyCharm**
Documentation upon entering the command and pressing Ctrl+Q in PyCharm (only an autogenerated docstring with the inferred variable type shows up): 
[image]

**Edit**
This question deals with the evaluation of external (e.g. matplotlibs or numpy) documentation decorators, not with how to write your own beautiful docstring.

Comment: the reason it works in jupyter is that the code is actually evaulated (much like in the interactive interpretter) whereas pycharm does not evaluate your code until you run it  ... (it is not running an eval loop for each line you enter)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "How to write the docstring of my own code.."?

Because, if you use [Sphinx/reStructuredText](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html) syntax, you can have beautiful documentation.

Here is a basic example:

```
def axhline_demo(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=1, hold=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Add a horizontal line across the axis.

    Parameters
    ----------

    :param y: scalar, optional, default: 0

        y position in data coordinates of the horizontal line.

    :param xmin: scalar, optional, default: 0

        etc.

    :param xmax: more documentation...
    :param hold:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
```

You'll get:

[image]

Use the Menu **View** => **Quick Documentation**.

Comment: no ... he wants it to evaluate matplotlibs documentation decorators ... I answered with this same thing 20 minutes ago and deleted it ... because im 99% sure this isnt quite what he is asking (what he wants cannot be done in pycharm afaik)

Comment: OK, didn't know that. He should reformulate his question…